# Why is GDB filling the 0s of a memory address with 5s during a register info?

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb, memory-address, cpu-registers

I am using GDB on a x64 CPU. As you can see, I am trying to access the value of the *rip* register and for some reason the address of the instruction the register is pointing to is displayed using 5s instead of 0s as it should be.

```
   Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000001139 <+0>:     push   rbp
   0x000000000000113a <+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp
   0x000000000000113d <+4>:     sub    rsp,0x10
   0x0000000000001141 <+8>:     mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x0
   0x0000000000001148 <+15>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x0
   0x000000000000114f <+22>:    jmp    0x1161 <main+40>
   0x0000000000001151 <+24>:    lea    rdi,[rip+0xeac]        # 0x2004
   0x0000000000001158 <+31>:    call   0x1030 <puts@plt>
   0x000000000000115d <+36>:    add    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x1
   0x0000000000001161 <+40>:    cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x9
   0x0000000000001165 <+44>:    jle    0x1151 <main+24>
   0x0000000000001167 <+46>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x000000000000116c <+51>:    leave  
   0x000000000000116d <+52>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1141: file Desktop/myprogram.c, line 6.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/william/Desktop/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at Desktop/myprogram.c:6
6         int i = 0;
(gdb) info register rip
rip            0x555555555141   0x555555555141 <main+8>
```

As you can see, the *rip* register contains the address of the `mov` instruction listed above but for some reason has replaced all the 0s for 5s. Any idea why?

Comment: Is your initial dump from object file? Then the addresses are just relative, before linking, also most of the modern OS-es do use ASLR while loading the executable, so you will have different `rip` upon every execution. Also it's highly unlikely any modern OS will give you such low addressing space, addresses around `0x000...` are often marked as not accessible to the user process, so any `nullptr` related memory accesses (bugs in app) will crash the app instead of providing some random values. The gdb operates on loaded instance of code, so the `rip` is some real value (vs object file dump).

Comment: @Ped7g My assumption would be that it's from `disassemble main` in gdb, but more context from OP would be nice.

Comment: @melpomene Thank you for reaching out! I am simply using GDB to disassemble an executable written in C. The code is simply a for loop that outputs "Hello World!" to the console 10 times before exiting. There is no other code outside of the main function so your assumption was correct. I'm really new with all that stuff so I must apologize if my explanations are insufficient. Mainly, I am wondering why the RIP register does not contain the same address as the instruction it is pointing too. It has the same end numbers but for some it reason it has replaced all the 0s of the address for 5s.

Comment: What happens if you `disassemble main` again after examining `rip`?

Comment: @melpomene all the zeros of the address of the instruction also shifted for 5s. I really could not explain why! I think you are onto something here. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're doing something weird.  NORMALLY the addresses seen in the gdb `disas` command and the address for $rip when you stop at a breakpoint should be consistent.  But the addresses shown in your dump are too small -- addresses smaller than about 0x10000 should always be invalid, and the text segment should be loaded at a higher address.  The Linux kernel will generally enforce this (though you don't say what OS you are using).  The address shown in $rip is plausible with ASLR, but normally gdb will disable ASLR for binaries it invokes directly with the `run` command, so that is also suspect.

Answer (score 3):

Before running a position-independent executable, there is no base address so gcc assumes `0`.  This matches what you'll see from `objdump -drwC -Mintel /bin/ls` or whatever.

On running the executable to create a process, the OS's program-loader maps it to an address.  x86-64 Linux chooses a page address that starts with `0x0000555555555...` when GDB disables ASLR.

If you run it outside GDB, or [with `set disable-randomization off`](https://outflux.net/blog/archives/2010/07/03/gdb-turns-off-aslr/), then the address will still start with `0x000055555`, but be randomized in some range.